# Input from a file

Tags: python, input, output

How to input from a file in python (the text that is in .txt is that I write myself) and check if the output is the same as in other file?

Basically I have test input file for my algorithm and test output file.

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutorial service. What have you tried and what went wrong with your attempts? Please provide a [mcve] with code based on your own research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all data at a moment:

```
with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

You can read all data line-by-line:

```
with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # todo smth
```